# Highlighting multiple lines in text from start index to end index (Range highlighting)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a long text and an array that contains a few objects. every object has a start key and an end key. What I am trying to do is to highlight the text, only on indexes I get from the array.

I wrote this code:

```
   function HighlightRange(text: any, start: any, end: any, color: any) {
    return (
      text.substring(0, start) +
      `<span style="background-color: ${color}">` +
      text.substring(start, end) +
      `</span>` +
      text.substring(end)
    );
  }
```

It works perfectly if I have only one object in the array. The thing is that when I use it, it changes the text and now it has a bigger length and the highlight now needs to get the new length in order to highlight the exact range.

I tried that:

```
     value?.input_spans.map((value: any, key: any) => {
      newString = HighlightRange(
        originalTextArea,
        value.start,
        value.end,
        "lightgreen"
      );
    });
```

Is it possible to iterate over all objects and highlight all text from start to end without changing the text length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the rare use cases of `.reduceRight()`. As @Robert Sabitz mentions starting from the end of the string would keep it's indices of interest unchanged.

```js
var prg = document.getElementById("lorem"),
    btn = document.getElementById("btn"),
    ixs = [{start:28, end:39}, {start:101, end:111}],
    clr = "lightgreen";
    
    
function highlighter(str,ixs,color){
  return ixs.reduceRight( (s,ix) => `${s.slice(0, ix.start)}<span style="background-color:${color}">${s.slice(ix.start,ix.end)}</span>${s.slice(ix.end)}`
                        , str
                        );
}

btn.addEventListener("click", _ => prg.innerHTML = highlighter(prg.textContent,ixs,clr));
```

```html
<p id="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dictum sapien, sit amet vestibulum ex tempus eget. Ut vitae.</p>
<button id="btn">Highlight</button>
```

Comment: Just wonderful... thanks for this clean solution!

Comment: @Redu Thanks! can you please help making it support nested/overlapping highlights?

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate from the end of the items to highlight (similar to removing elements from the array without updating the index). This way indexes from the beginning will stay correct.

The problem here becomes with nested/overlapping highlighting. If that's your case then it needs to be done one by one.

Example

```js
const spansToHighlight = value?.input_spans
if (!spansToHighlight) {
   return
}
let highlightedText = originalTextArea
for (let i = spansToHighlight.length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
   highlightedText = HighlightRange(
        highlightedText ,
        value.start,
        value.end,
        "lightgreen"
   );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! can you share an example based on what I did? @Robert Sabisz

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey, example added using the approach of adding changes from the end. Remember that nested/overlapping highlights will break here.